# Can angular-hammer (ryan mullins fork) wire up recognizers with `requireFailure`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hammer.js

In using the ryan mullins fork of [angular-hammer](https://github.com/RyanMullins/angular-hammer), I'm not clear on how to wire up several recognizers with `requireFailure` via the `hmRecognizerOptions` attribute... if it's even possible.

My perusal of the source left me with the impression it could be done, but I'm having a problem with sequencing the creation of the recognizers on a given element.

To see the problem firsthand, take the existing default demo, and add the following `hm-recognizer-options` attribute,

```all
<div id="target"
  ng-controller="hmCtrl"
  hm-pan="onHammer"
  hm-pinch="onHammer"
  hm-press="onHammer"
  hm-rotate="onHammer"
  hm-swipe="onHammer"
  hm-tap="onHammer"
  hm-doubletap="onHammer"
  hm-recognizer-options='[
  {"type":"pan","requireFailure":"swipe"}
  ]'>
  {{eventType}}
</div>
```

*(Also, see this plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/3sJFrC/preview
and the resulting error in the console)*

My hope was this would cause pan to be recognized only after swipe fails. However, stepping through the code reveals that the swipe recognizer has not been instantiated when pan is trying to reference it during the `requireFailure` call.

It's also not clear how this would ever work since it appears `requireFailure` (in HammerJS) automatically creates the reverse reference as well, via the `otherRecognizer.requireFailure(this)` line near the end of the method,

```all
/**
 * recognizer can only run when an other is failing
 * @param {Recognizer} otherRecognizer
 * @returns {Recognizer} this
 */
requireFailure: function(otherRecognizer) {
    if (invokeArrayArg(otherRecognizer, 'requireFailure', this)) {
        return this;
    }

    var requireFail = this.requireFail;
    otherRecognizer = getRecognizerByNameIfManager(otherRecognizer, this);
    if (inArray(requireFail, otherRecognizer) === -1) {
        requireFail.push(otherRecognizer);
        otherRecognizer.requireFailure(this);
    }
    return this;
}
```

In short, it appears both recognizers have to be instantiated before calling `requireFailure`, but angular.hammer.js treats the `hm-recognizer-options` on creation of each recognizer.

Am i missing a trick somewhere?
Or will I be creating my own directive that manages the requireFailure (and/or recognizeWith) wiring?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I'm also facing the sam problem.

Comment: @KeremDemirer Unfortunately, no. Shortly after posing this question, I changed projects... so I took no other action. At the time, though, I was tempted to try making the `otherRecognizer...` call a configurable option,  see how well it worked, and offer a PR to the maintainer.